# Using Windows Principles/Roles to programmatically control access to Controls/Forms - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, security, roles

The application in question is a fairly extensive with many different types of access roles (read Customer Service, HR, Admins, etc etc). Tiered access, so each role inherits the access below it, so HR has Read Only, CS has edit abilities, Admins full control. Menu bars and buttons enable/visible attributes are controlled by an outside an outside library that handles all role-based access via reflection. The man who wrote this was an evil genius.

That being said, I'd like eventually to remove it. The knowledge base on how it works left with him years ago, and development on this application is starting to stagnate since the documentation on the security 'suite' is awful. Everything is stored within  a database, down to label visibility for each label. It's a bit overboard and not refactor-friendly.

I've spent a solid amount of time looking into windows forms security. We're running our own user/roles for this app rather than Active Directory. I'd like to use User/Principal, since that looks like the best option. If there's another option, I'm open to advice, I'd like to see this done the right way since we're considering a full rewrite (unrelated to this).

All the searching I've done through MSDN and other websites has led me to believe that I can only control flow through methods and classes based on roles, not as granular as "enable this button" or "hide this menu bar."

Is there a better way than doing something along the lines of:

```
btnA.Visible = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("HR");  
btnA.Enabled = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("CS") ||  
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("ADMIN");
```

Is there a better way in general? What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty close to the way that we do it, both in WinForms and in our ASP.net applications.  The one difference is that we store the role names in a database so that they are easier to maintain and upgrade than hardcoded constants.

While it lacks the sexiness of some sort of automatic binding (which it seems that you are looking for), it's solid and has not been troublesome to deal with.  However, our application does not have a tremendous variation between users.  For the most part, if a user can get access to part of the application they can perform most of the actions.

Comment: I understand storing role names in a database, but how would you use them without using hardcoded constants? Only way I imagine right now is storing the constants off in a static Roles class, was that what you meant?

Comment: Thank you very much! It may not be sexy, but it will work, and that's something I can't say for much longer with our current implementation!